# How can I optimize a SPARQL query that returns optional properties?

Tags: sparql, marklogic, semantic-web, marklogic-8

How can I optimize a SPARQL query like the following?

The intent of this query is:

1. Specify a resource (country resource where `countryCode = "US"`)
2. Get back optional properties defined on the resource.

Unfortunately, the `OPTIONAL` blocks are being evaluated before the parent block, which causes the query engine to load all data for all countries.

What I want is something like a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` behavior, but the query engine is not handling it this way.

What can I do to improve query performance?

```
SELECT  *
WHERE
  { 
    ?type (rdfs:subClassOf)* gj:Country .
    ?this_0  rdf:type        ?type ;
             gn:countryCode  "US"
    # each of these blocks is executed as a standalone query in the engine
    OPTIONAL
      { ?this_0  gn:countryCode  ?countryCode_1}
    OPTIONAL
      { ?this_0  gn:name  ?name_2}
    OPTIONAL
      { ?this_0 gj:cscId  ?cscId_3} 
  }
```

I am using the SPARQL REST endpoint in MarkLogic 8.4.

**Update:**

I have tried querying with the *`optimize=2`* option, but it did not give me a significant performance improvement:

`/v1/graphs/sparql?optimize=2`

*Related:* [How do I specify options in the SPARQL REST endpoint for MarkLogic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43642453/how-do-i-specify-options-in-the-sparql-rest-endpoint-for-marklogic)

**Update 2:**

Even if I make one of the optional properties required, the query is still running slow:

```
WHERE
  {
        ?type (rdfs:subClassOf)* gj:Country .
        ?this_0  rdf:type        ?type ;
             gn:countryCode  "US"; gj:cscId ?cscId_3 ;
  }
```

Do I need to do something special to index this gj:cscId property?

**Update 3:**

Here is the profile information from the Query Console.

[image: Query profile]

**Update 4:**

Here is the diagnostic trace information:

```
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info: [Event:id=SPARQL Value Frequencies] sessionKey=13846462700334370907 namedGraphs=0 values=
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info: <triple-value-statistics count="154569757" unique-subjects="25445373" unique-predicates="104" unique-objects="67520361" xmlns="cts:triple-value-statistics">
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:   <triple-value-entries>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:     <triple-value-entry count="181">
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <triple-value>http://kb.everest.cscglobal.com/geonames-jurisdiction/1.0/schema#Country</triple-value>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <subject-statistics count="2" unique-predicates="2" unique-objects="2"/>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <predicate-statistics count="0" unique-subjects="0" unique-objects="0"/>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <object-statistics count="179" unique-subjects="179" unique-predicates="4"/>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:     </triple-value-entry>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:     <triple-value-entry count="15">
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <triple-value>http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf</triple-value>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <subject-statistics count="0" unique-predicates="0" unique-objects="0"/>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <predicate-statistics count="15" unique-subjects="15" unique-objects="5"/>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <object-statistics count="0" unique-subjects="0" unique-predicates="0"/>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:     </triple-value-entry>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:     <triple-value-entry count="8739716">
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <triple-value>http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type</triple-value>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <subject-statistics count="0" unique-predicates="0" unique-objects="0"/>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <predicate-statistics count="8359510" unique-subjects="8341619" unique-objects="14"/>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <object-statistics count="0" unique-subjects="0" unique-predicates="0"/>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:     </triple-value-entry>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:     <triple-value-entry count="8697064">
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <triple-value>http://www.geonames.org/ontology#countryCode</triple-value>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <subject-statistics count="2" unique-predicates="2" unique-objects="2"/>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <predicate-statistics count="8323137" unique-subjects="8323137" unique-objects="517"/>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <object-statistics count="1" unique-subjects="1" unique-predicates="1"/>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:     </triple-value-entry>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:     <triple-value-entry count="2119305">
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <triple-value datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">US</triple-value>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <subject-statistics count="0" unique-predicates="0" unique-objects="0"/>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <predicate-statistics count="0" unique-subjects="0" unique-objects="0"/>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <object-statistics count="2061783" unique-subjects="2061783" unique-predicates="3"/>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:     </triple-value-entry>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:     <triple-value-entry count="13946907">
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <triple-value>http://kb.everest.cscglobal.com/geonames-jurisdiction/1.0/schema#cscId</triple-value>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <subject-statistics count="3" unique-predicates="3" unique-objects="3"/>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <predicate-statistics count="11739004" unique-subjects="11739004" unique-objects="11739004"/>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:       <object-statistics count="0" unique-subjects="0" unique-predicates="0"/>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:     </triple-value-entry>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info:   </triple-value-entries>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.238 Info: </triple-value-statistics>
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info: [Event:id=SPARQL AST] sessionKey=13846462700334370907
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:   initialPlan=SPARQLModule[
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:   Prolog[]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:   SPARQLSelect[SPARQLProject[order()
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:       GraphNode[Var type 0]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:       GraphNode[Var this_0 1]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:       GraphNode[Var cscId_3 2]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:       SPARQLLeftNestedLoopJoin[order() hash(1==1) scatter(1 = 1)
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:         SPARQLNestedLoopJoin[order() hash(1==1) scatter(1 = 1)
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:           SPARQLScatterJoin[order(0,1) hash(0==0) scatter(0 = 0)
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:             SPARQLZeroOrOne[
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:               GraphNode[Var type 0]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:               GraphNode[IRI <http://kb.everest.cscglobal.com/geonames-jurisdiction/1.0/schema#Country>]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:               SPARQLScatterOneOrMore[
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:                 GraphNode[Var type 0]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:                 GraphNode[Var ANON16629111911678922088 0]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:                 GraphNode[Var ANON7634081659815295853 1]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:                 GraphNode[IRI <http://kb.everest.cscglobal.com/geonames-jurisdiction/1.0/schema#Country>]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:                 TriplePattern[order(0,1) PSO
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:                   GraphNode[Var ANON16629111911678922088 0]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:                   GraphNode[IRI <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:                   GraphNode[Var ANON7634081659815295853 1]]]]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:             TriplePattern[order(0,1) OPS
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:               GraphNode[Var this_0 1]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:               GraphNode[IRI <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:               GraphNode[Var type 0]]]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:           TriplePattern[order(1) SOP
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:             GraphNode[Var this_0 1]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:             GraphNode[IRI <http://www.geonames.org/ontology#countryCode>]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:             GraphNode[Literal "US"]]]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:         TriplePattern[order(1,2) PSO
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:           GraphNode[Var this_0 1]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:           GraphNode[IRI <http://kb.everest.cscglobal.com/geonames-jurisdiction/1.0/schema#cscId>]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:           GraphNode[Var cscId_3 2]]]]]]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info: [Event:id=SPARQL Cost Analysis] sessionKey=13846462700334370907 optimize=1 r=3 t=1.28811 os=360 is=15 mutations=30 seed=7088858925989728751
2017-04-27 13:30:17.239 Info:   initialCost=(m:5.99223e+11,r:0,io:(52.9404/167736/1.17487e+09),cpu(1):(0/1.77017e+08/1.18652e+12),mem:8185,c:1.03266e+07,crd:[14,2.06178e+06,1.03266e+07])
2017-04-27 13:30:17.320 Info: [Event:id=SPARQL Cost Analysis] sessionKey=13846462700334370907 diff=-5.98971e+11 diff%=-99.958 r=0
2017-04-27 13:30:17.320 Info:   cost=(m:2.51757e+08,r:0,io:(52.9404/322.031/4.68406e+07),cpu(4):(0/159/3.51041e+07),mem:415.68,c:6.46969e+06,crd:[14,2.06178e+06,6.46969e+06])
2017-04-27 13:30:17.320 Info: [Event:id=SPARQL Cost Analysis] sessionKey=13846462700334370907 diff=-5.98971e+11 diff%=-99.958 r=1
2017-04-27 13:30:17.320 Info:   cost=(m:2.51757e+08,r:0,io:(52.9404/322.031/4.68406e+07),cpu(4):(0/159/3.51041e+07),mem:415.68,c:6.46969e+06,crd:[14,2.06178e+06,6.46969e+06])
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info: [Event:id=SPARQL Cost Analysis] sessionKey=13846462700334370907 diff=-5.98971e+11 diff%=-99.958 r=2
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:   cost=(m:2.51757e+08,r:0,io:(52.9404/322.031/4.68406e+07),cpu(4):(0/159/3.51041e+07),mem:415.68,c:6.46969e+06,crd:[14,2.06178e+06,6.46969e+06])
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info: [Event:id=SPARQL Cost Analysis] sessionKey=13846462700334370907
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:   bestCost=(m:2.51757e+08,r:0,io:(52.9404/322.031/4.68406e+07),cpu(4):(0/159/3.51041e+07),mem:415.68,c:6.46969e+06,crd:[14,2.06178e+06,6.46969e+06])
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info: [Event:id=SPARQL AST] sessionKey=13846462700334370907
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:   plan=SPARQLModule[
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:   Prolog[]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:   SPARQLSelect[SPARQLProject[order(1,0)
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:       GraphNode[Var type 0]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:       GraphNode[Var this_0 1]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:       GraphNode[Var cscId_3 2]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:       SPARQLRightMergeJoin[order(1,0) hash(1==1) scatter()
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:         TriplePattern[order(1,2) PSO
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:           GraphNode[Var this_0 1]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:           GraphNode[IRI <http://kb.everest.cscglobal.com/geonames-jurisdiction/1.0/schema#cscId>]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:           GraphNode[Var cscId_3 2]]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:         SPARQLHashJoin[order(1,0) hash(0==0) scatter()
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:           SPARQLZeroOrOne[
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:             GraphNode[Var type 0]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:             GraphNode[IRI <http://kb.everest.cscglobal.com/geonames-jurisdiction/1.0/schema#Country>]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:             SPARQLBloomOneOrMore[
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:               GraphNode[IRI <http://kb.everest.cscglobal.com/geonames-jurisdiction/1.0/schema#Country>]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:               GraphNode[Var ANON7634081659815295853 1]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:               GraphNode[Var ANON16629111911678922088 0]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:               GraphNode[Var type 0]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:               TriplePattern[order(0,1) PSO
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:                 GraphNode[Var ANON16629111911678922088 0]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:                 GraphNode[IRI <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:                 GraphNode[Var ANON7634081659815295853 1]]]]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:           SPARQLMergeJoin[order(1,0) hash(1==1) scatter()
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:             TriplePattern[order(1) OPS
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:               GraphNode[Var this_0 1]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:               GraphNode[IRI <http://www.geonames.org/ontology#countryCode>]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:               GraphNode[Literal "US"]]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:             TriplePattern[order(1,0) PSO
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:               GraphNode[Var this_0 1]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:               GraphNode[IRI <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>]
2017-04-27 13:30:17.326 Info:               GraphNode[Var type 0]]]]]]]]
```

**Update 5:**

In some use cases, I found that I could eliminate the `?type` property path expression from the query. In one such case, performance improved by two orders of magnitude:

```
WHERE
  { 
    ?this_0  rdf:type        gj:Country ;
             gn:countryCode  "US"
    # each of these blocks is executed as a standalone query in the engine
    OPTIONAL
      { ?this_0  gn:countryCode  ?countryCode_1}
    OPTIONAL
      { ?this_0  gn:name  ?name_2}
    OPTIONAL
      { ?this_0 gj:cscId  ?cscId_3} 
  }
```

Since this solution changes the output of the query, it doesn't solve all of our use cases.

It seems that the problem is not with the OPTIONALs per se, but has something to do with the property path expression confusing the query planner, so that the properties in the OPTIONAL blocks are looked up indepedently (which is not performant).

Comment: OPTIONAL is a left join - I don't see any possibilities to improve the performance.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the non-optional part in an inner block?

Comment: @evsheino: Thanks for your comment! I tried it, and I didn't see any performance improvement.

Comment: I assume that the triple pattern `?this_0  gn:countryCode  "US" .` is the most restrictive pattern, and if so, I would move that to the top of the query. But if you are sure that the optionals are the culprit, then that doesn't help, of course.

Comment: Thanks! I am sure. If I remove the optional blocks, the query is on the order of 300ms. With the optionals, it takes upwards of 10 seconds. The query profile shows that each OPTIONAL block is executed as an independent query, before the parent query is executed, and that the OPTIONAL blocks are consuming most of the query execution time.

Comment: What's the query plan? You'll find this output in the logs if you enable the "SPARQL AST" trace flag. Also enable the "SPARQL Value Frequencies" and "SPARQL Cost Analysis" trace flags to find out more about the decisions made during optimization. https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/46/0/how-to-use-diagnostic-trace-events

Comment: @JohnSnelson Thanks. I added a screen cap of the profile info from the Query Console tool. The database is currently doing a reindex; I will try the other trace settings you mentioned when the reindex is done.

Comment: @JohnSnelson Updated with the trace information. Is there a catalog of support trace events somewhere in the docs?

Comment: @JohnSnelson Figured out that the original trace I posted was for a modified version of the query. I updated the trace to reflect the query I am currently testing with. I removed two of the OPTIONAL blocks to speed up troubleshooting a little bit, leaving only the most performance-critical one:


SELECT  *
WHERE
  {
     ?type (rdfs:subClassOf)* gj:Country .
     ?this_0  rdf:type        ?type ;
             gn:countryCode  "US";
    OPTIONAL
      { ?this_0 gj:cscId  ?cscId_3}
  }

Comment: Did you try the pattern in this order: `?type gn:countryCode  "US" ; ?this_0  rdf:type . ?type rdfs:subClassOf* gj:Country .` ?

Answer (score 5):

The query optimizer relies on using statistics to determine the best order for operations. Often there will be a restrictive triple pattern that can be used to restrict further operations using a scatter join.

In your case, the statistics don't provide such an obvious restrictive triple pattern. You can see by looking in the triple value statistics output that the string "US" occurs 2061783 times as an object - so that's not terribly restrictive.

The gj:Country IRI is restrictive (179 times in the object position), but unfortunately you need to use that on the right hand side of a transitive closure operator. It's very hard to predict how many results a transitive closure operator will return, as it depends a great deal on the actual data.

You'll find that using a property path like the one below will allow MarkLogic to avoid the zero-or-one operator, which may be a small performance boost:

```
?this_0 a/rdfs:subClassOf* gj:Country .
```

Going further if you know that (for instance) there is only one gj:Country with the country code of "US", you could add a limit to that part of the query to give the optimizer hints of how to treat the query, ie:

```
select * {
  {
    select * {
      ?this_0 a/rdfs:subClassOf* gj:Country .
      ?this_0  gn:countryCode  'US' .
    } limit 1
  }
  OPTIONAL { ?this_0 gj:cscId  ?cscId_3 } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Both of these changes had a significant performance impact. The prop path change cut it down to about ~5 sec, and the limit 1 clause cut it down to ~3 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Marklogic 8 seems to have a performance issue with property paths using `*`. Try replacing

```
?type (rdfs:subClassOf)* gj:Country .
```

with

```
{
   BIND(gj:Country AS ?type)
} UNION {
   ?type (rdfs:subClassOf)+ gj:Country .
}
```