# How do I specify options in the SPARQL REST endpoint for MarkLogic?

Tags: sparql, marklogic, semantic-web, marklogic-8

When I query the SPARQL endpoint for marklogic, I am trying to specify the optimize option:

`/v1/graphs/sparql?options=optimize%3D2`

This results in a 400 error:
`REST-INVALIDPARAM: (err:FOER0000) Invalid parameter: No configured options: optimize=2"`

What is the correct syntax to specify this and other options?

*Related:*
[How can I optimize a SPARQL query that returns optional properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43642183/how-can-i-optimize-a-sparql-query-that-returns-optional-properties)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See reference for [GET /v1/graphs/sparql](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/graphs/sparql).  There is an "optimize" parameter you can specify.  For example:

```
/v1/graphs/sparql?optimize=2
```

The "options" parameter accepts the name of persisted [query options](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search#id_48838).

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get this to work with the SPARQL REST endpoint. Do you know if there is also a way to specify this param when using the Query Console tool?

Comment: Do you mean calling the REST endpoint from Query Console?  Or using XQuery?  Or using Javascript?  Or SPARQL?  If XQuery, see the http://docs.marklogic.com/sem:sparql docs.  In particular, the third argument which accepts a sequence of strings, one of which can be "optimize=2".